# KeyError with name attribute set - Flask

Tags: python, html, css, forms, flask

I've searched all over StackOverflow and other sites for help with this problem and I'm pulling my hair out as I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to post a form to the Flask back-end to add an item to a 'Wishlist' in the database.

The idea is the user presses the button which is an image, this submits the form to run the code that adds it to the database.

This is my html for the button in question:

```
<input type="image" class="addlist" value="{{ product.id }}" name="addwish" alt="Add to Wish List" title="Add to Wish List" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='wishlist.png') }}">
```

and here is the Python Flask code:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addtowishlist():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        wishProductId = request.form['addwish']
        if wishProductId is not None:
            wish = Wishes(user_id=current_user.id, product_id=wishProductId)
            db.session.add(wish)
            db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

From what I understand, request.form[] method searches for the 'name' attribute in the dictionary. What I don't understand is that when clicked I get a server error:

> werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap..newcls: 400 Bad
>   Request: KeyError: 'addwish'

Everywhere else I've looked the solution is to just make sure the name attribute is correct, but as you can see, it is.

I can get it to work when I put a submit button around an img tag so I know that the code for posting to the database should be fine, but this just seems like bad form and it messes with my CSS and page layout.

Am I misunderstanding something here with the input tag with the type="image" and how it works?

Just to mention, I'm pretty new to Flask and this is my first application.

Thanks for any help

Comment: can you try `request.args.get('name')` or `request.form['name']`

Comment: Happened to me while i started out - did not give method="post" in the form.

Comment: vks: the former stops the error but then doesn't post anything to the database, the latter gives me the same error. Bitto: I have given the "post" method in the form, probably should have included that, sorry

Comment: Can you show the full Traceback Exception as well?

Comment: Can you also show the output for `print(request.form)` ?